# Find marginal cumulative distribution function from joint survival function

Tags: self-study, survival, cumulative-distribution-function

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two competing risks with joint survival function
$$
S(x,y)=\exp\{-x-y-0.5xy\}, 0<x,y.
$$
Find the marginal cumulative distribution function for $X$.

I know that the marginal survival function for $X$ can be found by plugging 0 in for $y$, which yields
$$
S_X(x)=S(x,0)=\exp\{-x-0-0.5x(0)\}=e^{-x}.
$$

How would I then get to the marginal cumulative distribution function?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a homework or similar self-directed study question. If so, please add the `self-study` tag and read the [site's guidelines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) about such questions. Are you familiar with the relationship between survival functions and cumulative distribution functions in general?

Comment: A univariate survival function $S_X$ is *defined* to be $S_X(x)=\Pr(X\gt x).$  The CDF is *defined* to be $F_X(x)=\Pr(X\le x).$  How are these probabilities related?

Comment: @whuber so since the survival function is the inverse of the cumulative distribution function, would my marginal CDF be 1 minus the marginal survival function I just found? I wasn't sure if the same property held for marginal distributions.